# Invoke a Struts2 action and consume result as Stream

Tags: java, struts2

Is this possible, within the Struts2 framework, and/or am I limited to using the URL/URLConnection classes to get the response as a stream? 
I've looked into the ActionComponent class but I'm not sure how to use it?

Thanks.

Comment: What is it that you are looking to do? Perhaps you're looking for something along the lines of: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29 ajax with long polling?

Comment: I'm trying to execute a few struts2 actions, and add them into a zip file. My actions respond with html, xls and pdf. Hope that helps, I looked at comet, but I don't think that fits my needs, directly anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is to use a StreamResult in your action.  Check out the following:

http://struts.apache.org/2.1.2/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/StreamResult.html

Here's an example for downloading a file:

http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-download-file-example/

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, the end result is a Streamresult, but what I am trying to do is is invoke a few other actions from within my action method, zip up all the responses and Stream out the zip file. My problem is that I can't actually figure out a way to invoke the actions from within my immediate action method. I hope that makes sense, sorry if I wasnt clear.

Comment: Why not have a static or singleton ZIP file then and after all the actions have completed (and you're ready to deliver your zip file), provide it as a Stream Result.  By the way, your original question says nothing about ZIP files, nor multiple actions; you might want to consider editing it.